# `scons run` target completion for zsh

Tags: zsh, scons

Is there `scons` target completion in zsh, similar to Makefile completion?

Comment: never heard of such a thing, assume you'd need to configure something yourself. Unlike build tools like rake, it's not that easy to get scons to spit out available targets from the command line. It's actually not that easy in make either. I suspect for the case mentioned here it's actually the `zsh-autocomplete` package doing the work, not zsh itself?

Comment: As the other of `zsh-autocomplete`, I can assure that it is, in fact, `zsh` doing the work for `make` target completion: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/bb61da36aaeeaa70413cdf5bc66d7a71194f93e5/Completion/Unix/Command/_make#L216

Answer (score 2):

No, [there isn't](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/c843af635a470f209e4aca70b26fcd74ed31071b/Completion/Unix/Command/_scons#L59).

Patches welcome, I'm sure.